# Trick to eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that if the rows of a matrix have the same sum then the sum is an eigenvalue. But what are the other eigen values? Also does it apply if only 2 have the same sum?

Comment: You'll probably get an answer here soon. But you'll learn more if you play with some $3 \times 3$ examples. You should be able to answer your own questions then.

Comment: In general you know nothing and no.

Answer (score 2):

No, this particular rule works only if *every* row has the same sum.

There's nothing particular mysterious about this: It's because the product
$$ A\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} $$
is a column vector whose entires are the row sums of $A$ -- so if *all* those row sums are the same, then $(1\cdots 1)^T$ is an eigenvector with that sum as an eigenvalue.

If only some of the row sums are the same, this tells us nothing.

And in any case we don't learn anything about *other* eigenvalues or eigenvectors this way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a matrix whose rows each have equal sums $a$. Then

$$ A \begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a\\\vdots\\a\end{pmatrix} $$

So one eigenvalue of your matrix is $a$. And one eigenvector of your matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\1 \end{pmatrix}$.

But this only works if each row sums to $a$. And you can't figure out the other eigenvalues just from this property. Think about it--$A$ could be anything from the identity to some more complicated matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Every square matrix has at least one eigenvalue.

By definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for the matrix $A$ if there exists a vector $v$ such that:
$Av = \lambda v$

if $Av = \lambda v$ then $(A-\lambda I) v = \mathbf 0$

and if $(A-\lambda I) v = \mathbf 0$ then $(A-\lambda I)$ is a singular matrix and $\det (A-\lambda I) = 0$

So, how to find the eigenvalues?  Calculate that determinant.  You will get a polynomial in terms of $\lambda$ and the roots of that polynomial will be eigenvalues of $A.$

One trick.

The characteristic polynomial will be $(-1)^n (\lambda^n - Tr(A)\lambda^{n-1} \cdots + \det(A)) = 0$

$Tr(A)$ is the trace of $A,$ which is the sum of the elements down the main daigonal.

So, frequently, if you know one eigenvalue, you can make an educated guess at the others.

In the case all the rows sum to the same value then $v= \mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector.  The sum of the rows as stated above will be an eigenvalue.

Comment: One is storing up trouble for the future if one thinks "every matrix has an eigenvalue".